# Appium - AWS device farm

Tags: appium, aws-device-farm, appium-android

I get an error as below when I try to run my tests on device farm. 
    `testAppiumMethod failed: Invalid server instance exception has occured: 
    There is no installed nodes! Please install node via NPM 
    (https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium#using-node-js) or download and 
    install Appium app (http://appium.io/downloads.html)`

I have installed `Appium` globally on local machine and the tests run fine. But they fail on device farm(have included all the dependencies). Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to invoke the Appium server through your code, which is not required in Device Farm. Device farm has a Test Spec file (which is a yaml file) which does it for you, so all yo need to do is connect your driver to the invoked Appium server.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the chance would you be able to provide this info:

- appium verion being used
- Specific method that the this failed on/code
  snippet
- Programming language Java/python
- How exactly are the test being packaged and uploaded? Are we using the web console or the SDK/CLI?
- Is this a web app tests or native app tests?

Also, to rule out an issue with a specific device would we be able to run the AWS Sample app/test on the same device?

Assuming this is an android test execute these commands to build the sample app:

```
git clone https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android.git
cd aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android/
./gradlew cC
```

The app-debug.apk should be located in ./app/build/outputs/apk/

Then clone the sample appium testng tests:

```
git clone https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app.git
cd aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app/
mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
```

The test pacakge "zip-with-dependencies.zip" should be located in the ./target directory

My apologies for adding all these questions as an answer. I look forward to your response.

HTH James

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you need to install node on your AWS instance.

See below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html